# Bluetooth serial connection between Raspberry Pi and Windows 10 times out after a short while

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, uart

I want to set up serial Bluetooth communication between a Raspberry Pi 3 with integrated Bluetooth module and a Windows 10 machine. The raspi is the server and runs a python script, that handles the connection and the data transmission. I have set it all up, following several tutorials in the internet and its working really good on the server side. I have tested the server with a serial terminal on my android phone and it was working as expected: All the messages were transferred correctly and it stayed connected as long as i wanted. Testing with my windows machine, on the other hand, caused a lot of problems. I have solved most of them and now i can connect my windows machine, over a serial terminal, to the raspi. My problem now is, that, after a short while, the connection dies, usually after 10 to 40 seconds, and i could not find a fix for that. The error message on windows is: `cannot open COM4` and the error message on the raspi is: `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`. 
Here is my python script, id that is actually the problem:

```py
import serial, bluetooth, subprocess, select

serialPort0 = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/serial0',
    baudrate = 115200,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

bluetooth.advertise_service(server_sock, "bluetoth_server", service_id=uuid,
                            service_classes=[uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                            profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
                            # protocols=[bluetooth.OBEX_UUID]
                            )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel", port[1], ", addr", port[0])

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from", client_info)

client_sock.setblocking(0)

while True:
    if not serialPort0.isOpen:
        raise Exception("Serial port closed unexpected")
        break
    ready = select.select([client_sock], [], [], 0.5)
    if ready[0]:
        blu_data = client_sock.recv(4096)
        if not blu_data:
            break
        serialPort0.write(blu_data)

    ser_data = serialPort0.readline().decode("utf-8")
    client_sock.send(ser_data)
client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

It reads data from a serial port and from a serial Bluetooth port and sends it to the other one respectively.
I am at a point, where i don't know what else to try and I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never,. i repeat, never use vCOM for Bluetooth communication. Use Bluetooth API instead (any one: Native or WinRT).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, that wont work. I need a solution for the vCOM, because I have a application, that i want to communicate on windows side and that application requires a COM port for serial communication. Also, it is not my application, so i can not change that.

Comment: Then use Serial Port profile as service UUID instead of custom UUID.

Comment: I have to admit, i am a bit lost there. where do i find that UUID, i have searched around a lot and found this: `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, but with this, the connection still fails, after a few seconds.

Comment: There are lot of things that may drop connection: power saving, bug in vCOM driver. Its not possible to say what can be wrong without using Bluetooth API. So write test app using Bluetooth API and see what happens. Then you can find what can be wrong. vCOM and Bluetooth is worst idea. Once you find what is going wrong and get correct disconnection reason code then it can be possible to understand why vCOM drops connection.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will try that.

Comment: I recommend to use any tgird party lib for testing. 32feet should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Your description related to timeout would be pointed to

/etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Bluetooth configuration file.

You will need to uncomment the pairabletimeout=0 that will prevent the timeout problems.

You may want to see Raspberry Bluetooth configuration (recent answer) for details.

[Bluetooth Serial Configuration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121216/how-to-best-handle-raspberry-pi-4-and-smartphone-connection-over-bluetooth-and-p)